# How to route different http post request to same instance using loadbalancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, load-balancing, ec2-ami

I have an application that sends video and a text file on different http post request. I have multiple ec2 instances under a loadbalancer. The video and text from a user must be sent to the same instance. Since I'm using a loadbalancer, is there any way to make sure that the both requests are sent to the same instance? Loadbalancer distributes traffic on multiple instances so I don't want the video to be routed to one instance and the text file to another instance. Can sticky session be used to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticky Sessions seems to be an [answer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_StickySessions.html) for this.